# For loop does not work correctly

Tags: javascript

I have problem with the first "for" loop. Loop do nothing but he should fill a array.

```
function isPrime(lowbound, highbound) {
  var primes = [];
  for (var i = lowbound; i < highbound; i++) {
    primes[i] = true;
  }
  var limit = Math.sqrt(highbound);
  for (var i = lowbound; i < limit; i++) {
    if (primes[i] === true) {
      for (var j = i * i; j < highbound; j += i) {
        primes[j] = false;
      }
      for (var i = lowbound; i < highbound; i++) {
        console.log(i + " " + primes[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  //end of isPrime
}
```

Is there anyone who help me ?

Comment: And how do you call it?

Comment: You can use `Array.fill()` in modern browsers to make things easier.

Comment: What are the values of `lowbound` and `highbound` ?

Comment: lowbound is lower bound or border in interval, I call it in Web Worker function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to get an array in the first loop?

```js
isPrime(2,10);

function isPrime(lowbound, highbound) {
  var primes = [];
  for (var i = lowbound; i < highbound; i++) {
    primes[i] = true;
  }
  console.log(primes);
  var limit = Math.sqrt(highbound);
  for (var i = lowbound; i < limit; i++) {
    if (primes[i]) {
      for (var j = i * i; j < highbound; j += i) {
        primes[j] = false;
      }
      for (var i = lowbound; i < highbound; i++) {
        console.log(i + " " + primes[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  //end of isPrime
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My call for this function is here:

```
onmessage=function Vypis(e) {
    var lowbound=e.data[0];
    var highbound=e.data[1];
    isPrime(lowbound,highbound);    
}
```